Attempted import error: 'MlAlert' is not exported from '@repo/ui' (imported as 'MlAlert') even though it definitely is 100% exported
I am building a web app using Turborepo, React and NextJS.
I have a package called @repo/ui and the package.json looks like this:
{
  "name": "@repo/ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "./src/index.ts",
  "types": "./src/index.ts",
  "sideEffects": [
    "**/*.css"
  ],
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tailwindcss -i ./src/styles.css -o ./dist/index.css",
    "lint": "eslint src/",
    "dev": "tailwindcss -i ./src/styles.css -o ./dist/index.css --watch",
    "type-check": "tsc --noEmit",
    "test": "vitest run"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@repo/eslint-config": "workspace:*",
    "@repo/tailwind-config": "workspace:*",
    "@repo/typescript-config": "workspace:*",
    "@repo/vitest-config": "workspace:*",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.4.8",
    "@testing-library/react": "^16.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.61",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.18",
    "jsdom": "^24.1.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.35",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3",
    "vitest": "^2.0.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "classnames": "^2.5.1",
    "react-icons": "^5.3.0"
  }
}

As you can see, I am providing types and main as ./src/index.ts which is where my component library is being exported from.
So I will go through their contents 1 index file at a time:
./src/index.ts:
export * from './components'

./src/components/index.ts:
export * from './atoms'
export * from './molecules'

./src/components/molecules/index.ts:
export * from './ml-alert'

./src/components/molecules/ml-alert/index.ts:
export * from './ml-alert'
export * from './ml-alert.types'

./src/components/molecules/ml-alert/ml-alert.tsx:
import cn from 'classnames'
import { AtIcon } from '../../atoms'
import { MlAlertProps, MlAlertType } from './ml-alert.types'

export const MlAlert = ({ type = 'default', icon, dataTestId = 'ml-alert', children }: MlAlertProps) => {
  const colorMap: Record<MlAlertType, string> = {
    default: '',
    info: 'alert-info',
    success: 'alert-success',
    warning: 'alert-warning',
    error: 'alert-error',
  }
  return (
    <div role="alert" className={cn('alert flex', colorMap[type])} data-testid={dataTestId}>
      {icon && <AtIcon {...icon} />}
      <span>{children}</span>
    </div>
  )
}

And here's what my login page looks like, where MlAlert is being imported:
'use client'
import { AtButton, AtTextbox, MlAlert } from '@repo/ui'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { FaLock, FaTimes, FaUser } from 'react-icons/fa'
import login from '../../actions/login'

const Login = () => {
  const [formError, setFormError] = useState<string | null>(null)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const submitForm = async (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    resetFormError()
    setLoading(true)

    const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget)
    const loginResponse = await login(formData)

    if (loginResponse && loginResponse.error) {
      setFormError(loginResponse.error)
      setLoading(false)
    }
  }

  const resetFormError = () => setFormError(null)

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col justify-center min-h-screen">
      <div className="flex flex-col items-center self-center">
        <div className="card card-bordered border-2 border-neutral bg-neutral w-full md:w-[30rem]">
          <div className="card-body">
            <h1 className="text-center">Login to StaticSync</h1>
            <div className="divider" />
            <form className="flex flex-col gap-4" onSubmit={submitForm}>
              <AtTextbox
                name="username"
                label="Username/Email Address"
                icon={{ type: FaUser }}
                disabled={loading}
                required
                onChange={resetFormError}
              />
              <AtTextbox
                name="password"
                label="Password"
                icon={{ type: FaLock }}
                type="password"
                disabled={loading}
                required
                onChange={resetFormError}
              />
              {formError && (
                <MlAlert type="error" icon={{ type: FaTimes }}>
                  {formError}
                </MlAlert>
              )}
              <div className="flex flex-col gap-2 items-center">
                <AtButton variant="default" loading={loading} type="submit">
                  Login
                </AtButton>
                {!loading && (
                  <a className="link link-secondary py-2" href="/register">
                    Register
                  </a>
                )}
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login

This all compiles perfectly, building it works fine, and even loading the page works fine. Yet, in development mode, when I navigate to the login page, I am greeted with:
web:dev: Attempted import error: 'MlAlert' is not exported from '@repo/ui' (imported as 'MlAlert').
web:dev: 
web:dev: Import trace for requested module:
web:dev: ./src/app/login/page.tsx

How is it that it doesn't complain about any of the atoms I'm importing (they're all exported using the exact same pattern as molecules), but complains specifically about this one molecule?

Okay, so I tested something - apparently if I create another molecule and export it the same way, such that there are at least two of them being exported, it works. What the frick?

In fact, even exporting the same molecule twice fixes it. I don't understand lol.
